# json_encode how to get the orginal array [stdClass Object]

Tags: php, json

Hello I have this json:

```
   [{"org_src":"img\/base\/logo.png","src":"\/cache\/300-logo.png"},

    {"org_src":"\/img\/l2.JPG","src":"\/cache\/6l-2.JPG"},

    {"org_src":"\/img\/studio\/desk.JPG","src":"\/cache\/desk.JPG"}, 

    ...
```

How looks the array before its is decoded?
If I use Json_encode to this, I will get this:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [og_src] => img/base/logo.png
            [src] => /cache/300-logo.png
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [og_src] => /img/l2.JPG
            [src] => /cache/6l-2.JPG
        )...
```

What is stdClass Object?
Thanks for any help in advance.

with json_decode($test,true); I will get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [og_src] => img/base/logo.png
            [src] => /cache/logo.png
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [og_src] => /img/studio/l2.JPG
            [src] => /cache/6l-2.JPG
...
```

This do not help me to see how the origin array looks like.

Here is the answer. That what I looked for. Thanks for any suggestion.

```
$stack[0][org_src]= "Hallo";
$stack[0][src] = "scrkjh";

$stack[1][org_src] = "Halfgfglo";
$stack[1][src] = "scrkjh";
json_encode($stack);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`stdClass`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php) is the base class of all objects in PHP. If functions like `json_decode()` create objects that are not of a special class type or other data types will be casted to object, stdClass is used as the data type.

You can compare it to the `Object` data type in Java.

---

You asked for an example how to access stdClass's properties, or in general, object properties in PHP. Use the `->` operator, like this:

```
$result = json_decode($json);

// access 'src' property of first result:
$src = $result[0]->src;
```

Comment: thx, but how does the array looks like to get this? if I do soemthing like this: $stack[1][org_src] = "Hallo";
$stack[1][src] = "scr";
the result is different

$stack[2][org_src] = "jhhgh";
$stack[2][src] = "123";

Comment: Use the `->` operator to access object properties. Like this: `$stack[2]->src`

Comment: do not get it. Example with $stack[2]->src??

Comment: "You asked for an example how to access stdClass's properties" No, I would like to create one.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

If you look in the docs, you will notice that there is `assoc` parameter if you want to get associative array instead of an object.

So you should do

```
$data = json_decode($data, true);
```

if you don't want objects

Comment: Hello, I do not wont to decode.
I#am looking for the array to encode, witch looks like the encoded example.

Comment: What exactly do you want? To get array from json, or the opposite? You said "If I use Json_encode to this, I will get this:", but that code you can get only with `json_decode`, not encode.

Comment: I would like to get the origin array of my example above.

Comment: Then use what I wrote you already. Json is *encoded* data. Process of getting it back to array is *decoding*.

Comment: but is in the example above not the same.
I have do create exactly this json output and do not know how.

Comment: You you should consider to add you edit to the question as an answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

stdClass is php's generic empty class, kind of like Object in Java or object in Python

It is useful for anonymous objects, dynamic properties, etc. and Stdclass Object is its object

See Dynamic Properties in PHP and StdClass for example

Also.. As Marko D said, You can use `json_decode($data, true);` true to get an associative array instead of object.